# ¿Como pasar estos datos de JSON a un panda dataframe?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, geojson

Tengo un archivo JSON y quiero pasarlo a un panda dataframe.
Leo el archivo y se lee bien salvo un campo que tiene la posición de latitud y longitud que me sale todo junto. Tengo que separar aambos campos y que salgan en columnas independientes.
El archivo json es asi:

[{"id":60,"title":"CALLE ALCALDE, 25","lastUpdated":"2020-01-28T00:00:00","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-0.9097477711138128,41.64174414911776]}},{"id":61,"title":"AVENIDA COMPROMISO, 70","lastUpdated":"2020-01-28T00:00:00","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-0.8623780839540626,41.64521112297201]}},{"id":62,"title":"AVENIDA CAMINO, 112","lastUpdated":"2020-01-28T00:00:00","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-0.8853951997519619,41.64033061129771]}}]

El codigo que utilizo es este:

```
import json, os
import pandas as pd

#leer fichero de datos .json
filename_in='parada.json'
f_in=open(filename_in, 'r')
content=f_in.read()
f_in.close()

df = pd.read_json(content)
df.tail(4)
```

Como resultado me saca la columna 'id', 'title', 'lastupdated y luego saca una 'geometry' , pero yo quiero sacar los datos que hay dentro de geometry, en coordiantes, que hay dos y sacarlas en una columna latitud y otra longitud.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que "desapilar" la clave `"geometry"` y llevarte sus datos al mismo nivel que las otras columnas.

Creo que lo más simple es cargar el JSON con Python, "masticar" el diccionario y luego pasarlo a Pandas:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

filename_in='parada.json'

with open(filename_in, "r", encoding="utf8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for parada in data:
    geo = parada.pop("geometry")
    parada["type"] = geo["type"]
    parada["latitud"], parada["longitud"] = geo["coordinates"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

> ```
> >>> data
>
>       id  title                       lastUpdated             type      latitud    longitud
> 0     60  CALLE ALCALDE, 25           2020-01-28T00:00:00     Point   -0.909748   41.641744
> 1     61  AVENIDA COMPROMISO, 70      2020-01-28T00:00:00     Point   -0.862378   41.645211
> 2     62  AVENIDA CAMINO, 112         2020-01-28T00:00:00     Point   -0.885395   41.640331
> ```

### Explicación

`json.loads`  siempre parsea el archivo a tipos nativos de Python (`dict`, `list`, `str`, `float`, etc), en este caso `data` es una lista de diccionarios.

[`dict.pop`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) es un método de la clase `dict` de Python, lo que hace es eliminar una clave del diccionario y retornar su valor. A cada diccionario de `data` por tanto le eliminamos la clave `"geometry"` y guardamos su valor en la variable `geo`. Para el primer diccionario `geo` será:

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-0.9097477711138128,41.64174414911776]}
```

y el diccionario `parada` queda:

```
{"id":60, "title": "CALLE ALCALDE, 25", "lastUpdated": "2020-01-28T00:00:00"}
```

A continuación, a ese mismo diccionario al que le hemos eliminado `geometry` le agregamos la clave `type` con el valor que tiene `geo` en esa misma clave. Además le añadimos las claves latitud y longitud  y le asignamos a cada una los valores de la clave `coordinates` de `geo`. El diccionario `parada` pasa entonces a quedar:

```
{"id": 60, "title": "CALLE ALCALDE, 25",
 "lastUpdated":"2020-01-28T00:00:00",
 "type": "Point",
 "latitud": -0.9097477711138128,
 "longitud": 41.64174414911776}
```

Comment: Hola, donde puedo ver la parte teorica de ese desapilamiento con 'pop'. Es para aprender para otros archivos mas complicados. Muchas gracias

Comment: `pop` es un método de la clase `dict` de Python, Lo que hace es eliminar una clave del diccionario y retornar su valor. Aquí tienes un enlace a la documentación oficial: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop. Ten en cuenta que json.load siempre parsea el archivo a tipos nativos de Python (dict, list, str, float, etc), en este caso data es una lista de diccionarios.

Comment: @kermit he editado la respuesta y he intentado explicar que hace el código con más detalle. Cualquier si sigues con alguna duda no te cortes en comentar, un saludo.